# Variant of the Coupon Collector's Problem with Two Probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, coupon-collector

The [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) is well-known in probability theory. Say there are $n$ types of coupons, where there is a probability of 1/n of getting each coupon with each draw. One expects to draw $n H_n = \Theta(n \ln n)$ (where $H_n$ is the harmonic number) coupons in order to get a complete set of all $n$ coupons.

I'm interested in a *variant* of this, where the $n$ coupons have *two possible probabilities*. Say $n_a$ of the coupons each have probability $p_a$ of being drawn, and the remaining $n_b = n - n_a$ coupons have some other probability $p_b$ of being drawn (with total probability $n_a p_a + n_b p_b = 1$, of course). I would like an asymptotic expression for the expected number of draws in order to get a complete set of $n$ coupons.

The exact answer is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations). In general, if each coupon has probability $p_i$, then the expected number of draws to get a complete set is
$$ \int_0^\infty \left[ 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - e^{-p_i t} \right) \right] dt. $$
Applying this to the problem at hand, we get
$$ \int_0^\infty \left[ 1 - \left( 1 - e^{-p_a t} \right)^{n_a} \left( 1 - e^{-p_b t} \right)^{n_b} \right] dt. $$
Question: *Is there an asymptotic expression for this?* That is, I'm looking for something analogous to the regular problem's $\Theta(n \ln n)$.

Comment: treat $n_a$ and $n_b$ as separate CC problems

Comment: Thanks @JonMarkPerry for the suggestion. As separate coupon collector problems, each expects $n_a H_{n_a}$ and $n_b H_{n_b}$ draws. But I'm not sure how to combine them with their respective probabilities $p_a$ and $p_b$.

Comment: the probability you pull a coupon of type a is $\frac{n_a}{n_a+n_b}$

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, thanks for the reply. I think I'm considering a more general problem. For example, say there are $n = 5$ coupons with respective probabilities of being drawn 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/4, 1/4. So the first $n_a = 3$ coupons each have probability $p_a = 1/6$ of being drawn, while the last $n_b = 2$ coupons each have probability $p_b = 1/4$. In this case, the probability of drawing a type-$a$ coupon is $3 \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$, not $\frac{n_a}{n_a + n_b} = \frac{3}{5}$.

Comment: so you'd have a coupon ratio 2:2:2:3:3 - makes sense